# Get project item ID from issue ID in Github GraphQL API

Tags: graphql, github-api

Is it possible to obtain the item ID of an issue within a project V2 from its issue ID using the GitHub GraphQL API, where multiple issues are held as project items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I used in my action

Basically we need projectId and issueId (issue.node_id). This will add the issue to the project if it not in the project. It will always return the same project itemId if the issue is in the project.

```yaml
    - uses: actions/github-script@v6
      id: get-project-item-id
      with:
        github-token: ${{ inputs.authToken }}
        script:
          |
          const query = `mutation($projectId:ID!, $contentId:ID!) {
              addProjectV2ItemById(input: {projectId: $projectId, contentId: $contentId}) {
                item {
                  id
                }
              }
            }`

          const variables = {
              projectId: "${{inputs.projectId}}"
              contentId: "${{inputs.issueId}}"
            };
          const result = await github.graphql(query, variables);
          core.info(`addProjectV2ItemById result: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
          core.setOutput("projectIdItemId",  result.addProjectV2ItemById.item.id);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to query the item ID of an existing issue, not the item ID of a newly added issue?

Comment: this will work with the existing as well. "It will always return the same project itemId if the issue is in the project."

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that part. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This worth registring on the stackoverflow after all this years of readonly!

Here's the query:

```
query($id: ID!){
  node(id: $id) {
  ... on Issue {
      projectItems(first: 10) {
        ... on ProjectV2ItemConnection {
          nodes {
            ... on ProjectV2Item {
              project {
                ... on ProjectV2 {
                  id, title
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```